# Problem in running simulation in omnet++ lost module

Tags: simulation, omnet++

I have built a project in omnet++ and i can't run the simulation and i get this message everytime even tho the project builds perfectly

i am using omnetpp 6

Class "veins::VeinsInetManager" not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel() -- in module (omnetpp::cModule) Network (id=1), during network setup

Launch a debugger with the following command?

opp_ide omnetpp://cdt/debugger/attach?pid=3880

and this error

Environment variables:
PATH=/home/simu5g/omnetpp-6.0/bin::/home/simu5g/omnetpp-6.0/bin:/home/simu5g/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/simu5g/omnetpp-6.0/bin:/home/simu5g/simu5g-workspace/simu5G/bin:/home/simu5g/sumo-1.11.0/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/simu5g/omnetpp-6.0/lib::/home/simu5g/simu5g-workspace/inet/src:/home/simu5g/simu5g-workspace/veins-veins-5.2/src:
OMNETPP_RELEASE=omnetpp-6.0
OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=/home/simu5g/omnetpp-6.0/images

what should i do?

I tried fixing properties but nothing changed